# Can I use Google Geocoding from VB.NET? (V3)

Tags: geocoding, reverse

I would like to use Google Map reverse geocoding from VB.NET if at all possible?

Jim

Answer (score 0):

It can be done definitely.

Reverse GeoCoding guide:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Sample URL to hit from your VB.NET code:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false

Use HttpWebRequest or WebClient.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even think of doing it that way.  Would you have any good examples of how I could read the JSON or even XML data from the Google response?

Comment: There is some sample code over at MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx#intro_to_json_topic5. Hope that helps! I dont have code specific to the API you requested.